# How to convert an object into a JSON_TABLE in MariaDB?

Tags: sql, json, phpmyadmin, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I have a `products` table which contains a `JSON` column `product_logs`. Inside of this, it contains something similar to:

```
{
  "c8eebc99-d936-3245-bc8d-17694f4ecb58": {
    "created_at": "2022-05-08T15:33:33.591166Z",
    "event": "product-created",
    "user": null
  },
  "ce7b171b-b479-332f-bf9e-54b948581179": {
    "created_at": "2022-05-08T15:33:33.591174Z",
    "event": "near-sell-by",
    "user": null
  }
}
```

I only want to return rows of products that have a `near-sell-by` event in the `product_logs` so I try to do this:

```
SELECT 
    products.*
FROM products,
     JSON_TABLE(product_logs, '$[*]', COLUMNS (
         created_at DATETIME PATH '$.created_at',
         event VARCHAR(MAX) PATH '$.event'
     ) logs
WHERE
    logs.event = 'near-sell-by'
```

However, I seem to be getting the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(product_logs, '$[*]', COLUMNS (
> created_at DATETIME PATH '$.cr...' at line 4

Any help to where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I edited to remove references to MySQL, because you are not using MySQL. MariaDB is a different product. It originated as a fork from MySQL in 2010, but both products have been gradually changing since then. You should not assume MariaDB is compatible with MySQL anymore.

Comment: Thank you @BillKarwin - truthly, I thought xampp came with MySQL but it appears it is MariaDB! I appreciate the knowledge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have copied, from another database, there is no varchar8max) in mysql, to syntax is a bit complicated, and you need to undestand json pretty well.

a gui like workbench, at least can help you identify the error, but it will not help you

> ```
> CREATE TABLE products (product_logs varchar(1209))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO products VALUES ('{
>   "c8eebc99-d936-3245-bc8d-17694f4ecb58": {
>     "created_at": "2022-05-08T15:33:33.591166Z",
>     "event": "product-created",
>     "user": null
>   },
>   "ce7b171b-b479-332f-bf9e-54b948581179": {
>     "created_at": "2022-05-08T15:33:33.591174Z",
>     "event": "near-sell-by",
>     "user": null
>   }
> }
> ')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     products.*,logs.created_at,logs.event
> FROM products,
>      JSON_TABLE(products.product_logs, '$.*'
>      COLUMNS (
>          created_at DATETIME PATH '$.created_at',
>          event Text PATH '$.event'
>      )) logs
> WHERE
>     logs.event = 'near-sell-by'
> ```

> ```
> product_logs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | created_at          | event       
> :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :------------------ | :-----------
> {<br>  "c8eebc99-d936-3245-bc8d-17694f4ecb58": {<br>    "created_at": "2022-05-08T15:33:33.591166Z",<br>    "event": "product-created",<br>    "user": null<br>  },<br>  "ce7b171b-b479-332f-bf9e-54b948581179": {<br>    "created_at": "2022-05-08T15:33:33.591174Z",<br>    "event": "near-sell-by",<br>    "user": null<br>  }<br>}<br> | 2022-05-08 15:33:34 | near-sell-by
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5402a268bc77ac79106ebd4ac3aaca8a)*

Comment: Thank-you for the detailed explanation, I think I'm running MariaDB because I get this error message running this: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(products.product_logs, '$.*'` Perhaps I'm not running `10.6` and should update?

Comment: only 10.6 supports full json_table see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=5402a268bc77ac79106ebd4ac3aaca8a so update or switch to mysql

Comment: Thanks @nbk I'm running `Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.24-MariaDB` I'll look to update this to `10.6` now. Thank-you very much for your time and explanation!